# Connecting in Dublin, Ireland

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, dub

I am flying from Edinburgh to Dublin with a 12:50 arrival time.  I then have a flight at 14:40 to Iceland.  Changing terminals and need to claim bags.  Also, an American traveling between these three countries.  Have I allowed enough time?

Comment: If you need to claim bags, I suppose that means the two flights are on separate tickets? Remember that means you need to have deplaned, cleared immigration, reclaimed your bags, walked to the check-in desk for your second flight, queued, and dropped your bags before the check-in deadline. If your incoming flight is late and you don’t make it, you’ll be considered a no-show, and the airline may cancel your tickets and all further segments automatically. Less than 2 hours for a connection on separate tickets is probably not a good idea at all.

Comment: Related:  [Transfer time from international to other flights in Dublin.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/transfer-time-from-international-to-other-flights-in-dublin)  While the situations are not quite the same, the extra 20 minutes you have may not be enough to make this feasible.

Comment: You should be able to make it, although barely. AFAIK, since you're arriving from Edinburgh, you will not go through arrival passport control in Ireland. And there is no departing passport control. You have 50 minutes to collect your bags, and bring them to check in to another terminal, which seem to be enough assuming your flight is on time, your bags are delivered within 25 minutes, and you don't get lost in the airport. You must be checked in already to your flight to Iceland, or you're cutting it too short though.

Comment: Looks like the Icelandair flights to KEF also depart from T1, so you might just have enough time. I'd be a bit nervous about it though.

Comment: @George Y All arrivals to Dublin go through passport control, even those from the UK. (The UK doesn't screen arrivals from Ireland, but the weirdness of the CTA is a whole other story)

Comment: @JoeMalt didn't know that, I always fly the other way, and there is never passport control.

Answer (score 2):

If your plane arrives on time, or a bit early, you should be able to make it but it will be tight.

Any delay will make it harder.

Arrivals from the UK are going through passport check in Dublin, then you need to collect your luggage, exit go to your new terminal and drop your luggage for the next flight, go through security and make it to your gate.
Even if your flights use the same terminal you will not be much faster, as you will need to exit and re-enter to drop of your luggage.

If you have not yet bought your tickets, I would want much more time for the transfer, 3 hours minimum but 5 hours would not be too long in my view.
Better to buy your connecting tickets always from the one airline, first of all, they will not sell if the connection is too short. Secondly they will take care of your luggage when changing planes (and mostly they will use the same terminal) and thirdly, they will get you to your destination if your incoming flight is delayed.